# Change Selected = true in SelectedListItem in ASP.NET MVC3 View by condition

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, drop-down-menu, asp.net-mvc-views

This is my Model:

```
public class MyModel{
 public string Name { get; set; }
 public string listType { get; set; }
 public string SelectedItem { get; set; }
}
```

I have a partial view:

```
@model List<MyModel>
@{

SelectListItem iEqualTo = new SelectListItem { Text = "Equel To", Value = "EqualTo" };
SelectListItem iNotEqualTo = new SelectListItem { Text = "Not Equal To", Value = "NotEqualTo" };
SelectListItem iGreaterThan = new SelectListItem { Text = "Greater Than", Value = "GreaterThan" };
SelectListItem iLessThan = new SelectListItem { Text = "Less Than", Value = "LessThan" };
SelectListItem iBetween = new SelectListItem { Text = "Between", Value = "Between" };


List<SelectListItem> MyFirstList = new List<SelectListItem>() {
    iEqualTo, iNotEqualTo, iGreaterThan, iLessThan, iBetween
};

List<SelectListItem> MySecondList = new List<SelectListItem>() {
    iEqualTo, iNotEqualTo
};

}


@foreach(var item in Model) {

  if(item.listType =="Firsttype"){

   <span> @Html.DropDownList(item.Name , MyFirstList) </span>

  } else {

   <span> @Html.DropDownList(item.Name , MySecondList) </span>

  }
}
```

So I need `Selected = true` in `List<SelectListItem>` in `DropDownList` that item which name equal to `MyModel.SelectedItem`? what is your suggestion? In actual my view have more `SelectListItem` and `List<SelectListItem>` and for some limitations I can't pass the `List<SelectListItem>` as my model property and I need to handle it in view. I think to handle it by lambda inline but I don't know is possible, something like this: `@Html.DropDownList(item.Name , MySecondList.each(a=> if (a.ToString() == item.SelectedItem) {a.Selected = true})`

Is any way to do this? and if I am wrong to use inline lambda does any other way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a SelectList, which has a constructor with an IEnumerable and an Object (selected value).

```
@Html.DropDownList(item.Name, new SelectList(MyFirstList, item.SelectedItem));
```

**EDIT**

I think I faced your problem when trying to use a DropDownList in a loop.

You can try to use this generic extension method (in a static "helper" class)

```
public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ToSelectListItem<T, TValue, TText, TSelectedValue>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable,
            Func<T, TText> text,
            Func<T, TValue> value,
            TSelectedValue selectedValue)
        {
            return enumerable.Select(item => new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = text(item).ToString(),
                Value = value(item).ToString(),
                Selected = value(item).Equals(selectedValue)
            }).AsEnumerable();
        }
```

and then

```
@Html.DropDownList(item.Name, MyFirstList.ToSelectListItem(m => m.Text, m => m.Value, item.SelectedItem)
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems very good idea, but I have a problem I use this: `@Html.DropDownList(item.Name, new SelectList(MyFirstList, "EqualTo"));` but that not worked and returned 5 times `System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem` it seems this code can't bind the select list correctly, what do you think?

Comment: Order of parameters you use is: 1-`Func<T, TText> text` ,2-`Func<T, TValue> value`

Comment: Yes yes, you're right, I don't know how to use my own methods. Corrected.